# Schengen visa renewal for Indian citizen to go to Switzerland, after having one issued by Portugal consulate in Los Angeles

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a boss from India, living in US with an H1B visa and is in the process to get a green-card. He went to Portugal in March 2018, and we processed his Schengen visa via a specific agency provided by the Portuguese Embassy web-page.

At the occasion, we were told that:

> "Should he have had a recent Schengen visa from the last 2-3 years,
>   please include its copy and if deemed qualified to submit by mail, we
>   will explain the alternate procedure for him to follow."

The question is: would he need to go in person to a Swiss consulate now, as he has a business trip to this country? And would this be necessary every time he travels to Europe with difference of time higher than 90 days?

Answer (score 3):

The main purpose of visiting the consulate is to capture the biometrics. Since he has already been issued a Schengen visa in the past five years, there should be no need to visit the Swiss consulate as his biometrics should already have been collected the last time he applied. You can directly mail (if they agree to) all the documents to the consulate without worrying about going there in person.